# Function to automatically check correct R package version is installed

Tags: r

In my job it is essential that all staff are using the same version of R and the same version of each package.

I have created a local CRAN repository and a function that installs straight from this repository.

The problem is at my work there is a lot of staff and the only way to ensure everyone has done this is to manually check myself.

I was wondering if there exists a way to automatically check that you have the correct package installed?

For example if boot_1.3-18 is the package I wish everyone to use, can I make a function to check whether an R library contains this version?

Also if possible (but not essential) to do this with the version of R being used would be fantastic!

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: You can access the package version through `packageDescription("packagename")$Version`. You can see the same for all installed packages using `install.packages()[,c("Package", "Built")]`. Does that help?

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for many thanks. Is there a similar way to do this for the version of R that is being used?

Comment: Maybe use [MS Open R](https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/open/), or use VM to have one R shared by all users.

Comment: So *for different projects* they are forced to use the same versions? Boy would I hate to work there …

Comment: Hi Konrad, no I probably didn't explain very well. It is the same project for all that need locked down package versions.

Comment: @Frost_Maggot OK, apologies for the assumption. That sounds a lot more sensible now! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Checking versions for a specific package**

You can access the package version through. An example for the `abind` package:

```
packageDescription("abind")$Version
# [1] "1.4-3"
```

**Checking versions of all installed packages**

```
installed.packages()[,c("Package", "Built")] 
# Gives an overview of all installed packages and the versions of those packages.
#                   Package            Built  
# abind            "abind"            "3.2.3"
# BradleyTerry2    "BradleyTerry2"    "3.2.3"
# brglm            "brglm"            "3.2.3"
# car              "car"              "3.2.4"
# caret            "caret"            "3.2.4"
# colorspace       "colorspace"       "3.2.4"
# devtools         "devtools"         "3.2.5"
# (...)
```

**Checking current version of `R`**

```
sessionInfo()$R.version$version.string
# [1] "R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)"
```